# SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState how to?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity, viewpagerindicator

I am working on a application which has multiple fragments, where I am using ViewpageIndicator library and Sherlocakactionbar library. In one of fragment, I have to a button which will call intent as startactivityforResult to get image from camera.. But the error I am getting is to savefragmentBasicState. I have worked in Activity and know it but I still dont understand how this fragment works and people are doing from so make ways which make me more confuse. how should i save the state??

**Addmonitoring.java**

```
public class Addmonitoring extends SherlockFragmentActivity {


    private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Info",
            "Budget", "Accessibility", "Engagement", "Effictiveness",
            "Additional Info","Documents","Picture","Video","Finalize" };

    private FragmentPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager pager;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    private static final int[] ICONS = new int[] {
            R.drawable.ic_info, /* info */
            R.drawable.ic_budget, /* budget */
            R.drawable.ic_accessibility, /* accessibility */
            R.drawable.ic_engagement, /* Engagement */
            R.drawable.ic_effectiveness, /* Effectiveness */
            R.drawable.ic_additionalinfo, /* Additional info */
            R.drawable.ic_documents, /* Documents */
            R.drawable.ic_photos, /* Pictures */
            R.drawable.ic_video, /* Video */
            R.drawable.ic_addmonitoring_info /* Save */
    };
    String projectid;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    dbhelper db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addmonitoring);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();


        adapter = new StarterMenuAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)  findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);

        pager.setCurrentItem(0);

    }

    class StarterMenuAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter implements
            IconPagerAdapter {
        public StarterMenuAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragmant = null;
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragmant = new Fragment1_info();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragmant = new Fragment2_budget();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragmant = new Fragment3_accessibility();
                break;
            case 3:
                fragmant = new Fragment4_Engagement();
                break;
            case 4:
                fragmant = new Fragment5_Effectiveness();
                break;
            case 5:
                fragmant = new Fragment6_AdditionalInfo();
                break;
            case 6:
                fragmant = new Fragment7_Document();
                break;
            case 7:
                fragmant = new Fragment8_Pictures();
                break;
            case 8:
                fragmant = new Fragment9_Video();
                break;
            case 9:
                fragmant = new Fragment10_Save();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
            return fragmant;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length];
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconResId(int index) {
            return ICONS[index];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return CONTENT.length;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

}
```

**Fragment8_Pictures.java**

```
public class Fragment8_Pictures extends SherlockFragment implements
        OnClickListener {

Uri capturedImageUri = null;
    ImageView image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addmonitoring8_picture,
            container, false);
    image1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mon_image1);
    image2 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.mon_image2);

    image1.setOnClickListener(this);
    image2.setOnClickListener(this);

    return view;

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.mon_image1:
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                ("devcheck_monitoring" + cal.getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg"));
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            file.delete();
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent i = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(i, 301);

        break;

    }

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 301) {
        // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        // imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                    capturedImageUri);
            image1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Logcat error

```
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentBasicState(FragmentManager.java:1576)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManager.java:1617)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:481)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:127)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1152)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1216)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3257)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3316)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1274)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5232)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:561)
08-20 10:58:57.223: E/AndroidRuntime(6131):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: but the error is not here!

Comment: @SherifelKhatib : i didnt understand what you mean?? I have posted the logcat there..

Comment: The error in your logcat is not in the code you posted.

Comment: wtach out for "Caused by:"-phrase further down the trace!!